# Extract all BUT the last word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've got the following statement that successfully extracts the Last Word within a Field.

```
select right(rtrim([FIELDNAME]),charindex(' ',reverse(rtrim([FIELDNAME]))+' ')-1)
```

However, does anyone know you can extract everything up to the last word?

For example:

Joe Michael Bloggs would turn into "Bloggs" and "Joe Michael"

Comment: You've surely played around with similar logic, its just going to be `substring(0,index)` rather than `substring(index,end)`

Comment: Something like: `substring([FIELDNAME]), 1, len(reverse(rtrim([FIELDNAME])) - charindex(' ',reverse(rtrim([FIELDNAME]))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CROSS APPLY to calculate the position ONCE.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Joe Michael Bloggs')
,('Mary Smith')
,('Cher')
 
Select SomeCol
      ,LastWord = right(SomeCol,Pos)
      ,TheRest  = rtrim(left(SomeCol,len(SomeCol)-Pos))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (charindex(' ',reverse(SomeCol)+' ')-1) ) B(Pos)
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol             LastWord    TheRest
Joe Michael Bloggs  Bloggs      Joe Michael
Mary Smith          Smith       Mary
Cher                Cher
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method based on XQuery. Its data model is based on **ordered sequences**. It makes it very easy to get last token via `last()`, or any other token.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Joe Michael Bloggs'),
('Mary Smith'),
('Marie Odette Rose Bellino'),
('Cher');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, tokens
      , c.query('data(/root/r[position() lt last()])').value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)') AS [LeadingTokens]
      , c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)') AS [LastToken]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, SPACE(1), ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID |          tokens           |   LeadingTokens   | LastToken |
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Joe Michael Bloggs        | Joe Michael       | Bloggs    |
|  2 | Mary Smith                | Mary              | Smith     |
|  3 | Marie Odette Rose Bellino | Marie Odette Rose | Bellino   |
|  4 | Cher                      | NULL              | Cher      |
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+-----------+
```